# Choosing specific lines from a data file

Tags: python, plot, data-manipulation

Hi I'm trying to extract some specific lines from my data file which satisfies my conditions. My data file looks like this:

```
10.0    950.0   123.315408      416.684182      60.0000004
10.0    900.0   125.687425      416.420677      60.0000004
10.0    875.0   126.577457      416.252579      60.0000004
12.0    950.0   122.791462      416.899612      60.0000004
12.0    925.0   124.181433      416.78099       60.0000004
```

I want to print out the lines where the second column has a value of 950.0 and then plot from that file. I thought it would be easier to first extract the info to a file and than plot it. If its possible to plot first and 3rd column while 2nd is constant it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your data is not separated with tab please check it once .
please try this

```
x=[]
y=[]
for line in open("data.dat"):
    if line.split()[1]=='950.0':
        newdata.write(line)
        x.append(line.split()[1])
```

Comment: I'm actually extracting this data by using following piece from my code:
for x, y, z, t, k, j, l in zip([TanBeta], [A0param], [Muparam], [Alparam], [Mhiggs], [ChiO], [MRHSN]):
data.write(str(x) + '\t' + str(y) + '\t'+ str(z)+'\t'+str(t)+'\t'+str(k)+'\t'+str(j)+'\t'+str(l)+'\n')

so it should be separated by tab i suppose and code above works fine if I just want to plot those columns

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do with numpy. [`numpy.loadtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) will import your entire data file as a 2D numpy array. You can then make another array of only those lines in which the second column has some value with [`numpy.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). You could turn this array from a list of rows to a list of columns with [`numpy.transpose()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html), which would make it easy to select only the first and third columns with something like:

```
x=transposed_arr[0]
y=transposed_arr[2]
```

and then make a scatter plot with matplotlib.